# Why does R give me a wrong value when I use the mean function?

Tags: r, mean

When I calculate the mean of the following:

```
 mean(c(-2.1,-0.2,-1.1,-0.5,2.5,1.4))
[1] -0.00000000000000004627736
```

I get a result that is not 0 although it should be zero (you can calculate it yourself with a calculator)

Comment: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558)

Comment: Computers are not very good with floating point numbers and they do math differently than we humans do it. When working with decimal values, some small "errors" may appear. The value returned is close enough to 0 for most practical purposes.